# Possible code highlighting bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, syntax-highlighting

In the question that I answered, I had two code blocks.  The first code block I used `tick` marks, the second I pressed the icon above the editor { }

The first code block does not receive syntax highlighting and the second one does.  Are `tick` marks not meant for code?

[Post a disabled select field PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263076/post-a-disabled-select-field-php/11263135#11263135)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is by design. The backticks are for inline code, usually a single "word". You use it for stuff like `root` and `abstract` and `enum` and `live()`, etc. It will not appear on its own line unless you force it to.

A whole line of code is better put in the block codeblock--it gets its own line and is syntax highlighted as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'll accept it after 11 minutes.

Comment: @alexy13: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 6):

Code between backticks are not highlighted. Only code in code block is highlighted.